# How did the Horsemen reach the plane in a truck?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me-2

In *Now You See Me 2*, the Horsemen reach a plane site in a truck, seat in the plane and set up the whole thing. When the curtains are off, they were at the middle of a river. They saw that the plane was not flying but they have set up fans to make others think that it's flying.

Police needs to reach that place by boat to catch them. So how do they reach that place in a truck?

Answer (score 3):

- The truck arrived at the hanger, with the plane inside
- Everyone boarded the plane
- The plane was towed from the hanger onto a barge
- Then the barge was towed into the river.

Comment: Good imagination. But no proof of this.

Comment: Did you want me to interview the characters in the fictional movie? If it wasn't explicitly shown on screen, then of course there's no proof. The method above was heavily suggested by the film.

Comment: And then they use hanger to stop barge in the middle of river?